C$_{60}$ fullerene electronic structure, C$_{60}$ insulator
I read a post on Chemistry stackexchange, how to explain that C$_{60}$ is an insulator. The common ground seemed to be that -- in contrast to graphene -- a C$_{60}$ solid consists of separate molecules and therefore electrons would need to jump. So even if there was conductivity on a single molecule, this still inhibits conductivity.
However, I came across this website and the sources therin (escpecially this one), which say that C$_{60}$ is an insulator because of the electronic structure. In the model there are no half occupied orbitals and the energy gap to the next state is about 1.9eV.
From that I would conclude it is an insulator or semiconductor, right?
Furthermore, when doped, there is significant conduction, which would falsify the 'need to jump' argument.(?)
So what is the correct explanation for C$_{60}$ by itself being a bad conductor?


The need to jump explanation is correct. With no half filled levels, the next energy level is a long way above the highest full level. Very few electrons will be in that level from thermal excitation.
An electron in one C$_{60}$ must to jump an empty level in another for conduction to occur. That could happen to one of the very few electrons in a high level, but not to an electron in the filled levels.
Doping changes things by introducing levels not much higher than the filled level. Electrons do populate empty levels from thermal excitation.
Not only can the excited electrons jump. But now there are "holes" in the filled levels. Electrons in those levels have a place to jump in a neighboring
C$_{60}$.
